# How to use a Http2SolrClient with Proxy

Tags: java, spring, solr, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using the Apace Solr Library to access a Solr Api in my Java Spring project.

maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My SolrClient configuration looks like this:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SolrConfig {

  @Value("${proxy.host}")
  private String proxyHost;

  @Value("${proxy.port}")
  private int proxyPort;

  @Value("${proxy.username}")
  private String proxyUsername;

  @Value("${proxy.password}")
  private String proxyPassword;

  @Value("${solr.host}")
  private String solrHost;


  @Bean
  public SolrClient getSolrClient() {
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .setProxy(proxy)
        .build();

    return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrHost)
        .withResponseParser(new XMLResponseParser())
        .withHttpClient(httpclient)
        .build();
  }
}
```

Everything works perfectly. However since version 9.0.0 (which I am using) the class HttpSolrClient is marked as deprecated. As far as I know I'm supposed to use the class Http2SolrClient instead.

Sadly I can't figure out how to add my proxy server configuration to an Instance of Http2SolrClient.

Comment: Look's like it's not possible anymore. You might want to fill a bug at Solr GitHub/JIRA.